# Avoid 1+n queries in Django admin list view

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a Django model:

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    @property
    def slug(self):
        return slugify(self.author.name)
```

Now if I add `slug` field to admin `list_display`, there will be a separated query for each instance.

How to make just one query for all instances?

I tried to use `select_related` in the `ModelAdmin` class, but I did not get it working.

Comment: No there won't. That would only happen if `title` was a ForeignKey.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, you are correct. I not reworked my question to include a foreign key.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can override get_queryset() of your ModelAdmin to add your select_related.

```
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset(request).select_related('author')
```

Answer (score 4):

There is also the [list_select_related option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_select_related), which I believe to be is much more direct.

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_select_related = ['author']
```